# cpu's fan increases without reaching a settle point

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan, cooling

I'm encouterning the followning phenomenon on the hardware side of a pc: When powering up the machine, the cpu's fan (cpu cooler's fan accuratelly) is starting to rotate, but it doesn't settle down to a certain angular speed (rpm), instead the latter keeps increasing with a small rate. I also noticed that when putting the computer into stand by mode, the fan kept rotating!

The motherboard is a Gigabyte 81945PL-G. The cooler is the one that came with the motherboard, an Intel c91 968-004 (as it is displayed in the fan's label). The cpu is an Intel Pentium Dual Core at 3.2 GHZ.

The problem is clear due to the noise of the fan, which increases with time. I think it's going to explode it i let it work for an hour or so. Apparently, it can't be related to cpu's temperature since the machine is in power off state for a long time and when i power it on, the cpu is cold.

The bios settings related to the fan, haven't been changed by anybody. Any help on that please?

Comment: Sounds entirely normal.

Comment: A few more details would be appreciated to precisely diagnose the problem here. Firstly, what is the make/model of the CPU, CPU cooler, and motherboard? Additionally, how is the fan attached to the computer, is it using a PWM port (4 pins), or a 3-pin fan port. By default, the fan settings are tuned to keep the processor temperature below a certain threshold. So if the fan keeps accelerating, that means the system thinks that the CPU is still above that threshold and increases the fan speed to compensate. Sometimes this basic profile is still active in standby.

Comment: Who told you that i worked this machine for 1 hour? The first time that this happened, i stopped the pc right into 2 minutes and never worked again on it. Next time you post a comment please have something essential to say.

Comment: If the fan speed is unstable two minutes into operation, then more likely than not the cooler has poor interface contact with the heatspreader (the metal plate on top of the silicon) and the thermal interface material (commonly referred to as 'thermal paste') needs to be replaced OR the cooler needs to be more snug against the surface of the heatspreader.

Comment: Did this fan ever behave the way you expect it to?  If so, has anything changed/been done to the system since then? What makes you think it's currently not working as it's configured to?  Have you looked in the BIOS for Fan settings? What are they set to?  Have you examined the cooling apparatus to ensure all the elements (fan, heat sinks etc.) are seated properly, and have no damage? Basically though, so far this question (to me) just seems to be "My CPU fan spins when I turn on my computer, I think it's not supposed to for some reason, is it the motherboard or the fan that failing?"

Comment: Voting to close because it's unclear (IMO). Please edit your question to add some clarity, including your expectations, what you've tried already, and what the results were. Then ask us a specific question, instead of asking us which one of your two guesses are the problem.

Comment: The motherboard is a Gigabyte 81945PL-G. The cooler is the one that came with the motherboard, an Intel c91 968-004 (as it is displayed in the fan's label). The cpu is an Intel Pentium Dual Core at 3.2 GHZ.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. The fan speed would vary all the time at the slightest change in CPU usage making the sound of it impossible to get used to.

My solution to all fan speed issues<sup>**1**</sup> is to install [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php). There are also a [few alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/speedfan/?platform=linux) for linux should that be your OS of choice.

<sup>**1**</sup>Besides regular cleaning